# How to write a Wix Custom Action to Read XML data and set Properties

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I have been working on this for days and I just don't get the concept of how Custom Actions work with Wix.   Or at least I don't see how to do what I want.

I have several XML files that I want to read a value from and populate a property that gets displayed in a UI Dialog.  Then when the install begins update that value in another XML file.

I need to be able to pass the filename including path of the local XML file  and the node to search for and the key value pair to extract.  I also need to pass what property needs to be updated.

I understand the CustomAction DLL concept.  And that the session.CustomActionData["parametername"] syntax for passing in parameters.  And the session["property"] =  to set a property.

But I can't figure out the syntax of the wsx code to make it all happen.  I read different examples doing it different ways?

I searched all the Google links out there an nothing seems to fit what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You want this to be an immediate custom action not a deferred custom action so CustomActionData has no relevance to you.

What I would do is write a custom table like such:

Id  [PK]
File (Formatted)
XPATH
Property

Here's an example:
mySearch
[SOMEPROPERTY] 
/test[@'test']  (something like that, I hate xpath)
MYPROPERTY

You can use things like Property/FileSearch to have MSI's AppSearch resolve the location of a file and assign it to [SOMEPROPERTY].  Then you write a custom action scheduled after AppSearch to fetch this table's data, iterate it and fetch the attribute value (or element innertext)  of each row and assign it to MYPROPERTY.

InstallShield gave this to me for free.  I don't think WiX has a built in extension to do this.  Maybe there is a community extension out there.  It would probably take me an hour to write a prototype of this in C#/DTF.

Comment: I understand your comment about the CustomActionData no being relevant for immediate actions.  But I don't know what you mean by a custom table and what your example means?

Comment: See if this connects the dots: http://blog.iswix.com/2008/05/data-driven-managed-custom-actions-made.html

Comment: Nope....that didn't make sense either?  I am doing this using Visual Studio 2013 using C#.